# upload large file in nodejs with multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, upload, multer

I want to be able to upload large file with React in NodeJS. To do this, I used a multer. I wanted to know if there is a time when the Internet is cut off, there is a way to continue uploading after connecting to the Internet.